# collectd-how to install write_riemann plugin

Tags: plugins, centos, yum, collectd, riemann

I'm new to collectd and Riemann. Im essentially trying to direct collectd logs to a riemann server instance. I understand that I need write_riemann plugin installed. I tried compiling the source files for write_riemann available online, but it includes a file called "riemann.pb-c.h", which is no where to be found. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Download the binary. After running the build script, while running the configure script include "--enable-write_riemann", this should install it. I had a lot of dependencies missing on CentOS, which threw a lot of errors. Once they were installed, write_riemann plugin was compiled and installed. Another issue you might face while installing the dependency is not able to find the right packages for protobuf-c.I was using yum package installer. Go to sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo and change enabled from 0 to 1. After this, the protobuf-c processor was recognised while running the configure script. This solved my issue. Hope it does yours too!